# How to test npm package shipped as .tgz file in react using jest?

Tags: reactjs, npm, jestjs, jointjs, rappid

I'm using a npm package shipped as .tgz file with in a react application. But when I try test a react component using jest which imports this package I'm getting the following error. Is there anything that I have to configure in jest to test this?

```
    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

    Here's what you can do:
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

    Details:

    D:\application\node_modules\@clientio\rappid\build\package\index.ts:14
    export * from './rappid';
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'


    > 4 | import * as joint from '@clientio/rappid/build/package';
        | ^

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:537:17)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:579:25)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/../hmy-component.js:4:1)
```

My package.json looks like below.

```
{
...
"dependencies": {
...
 "@clientio/rappid": "file:vendor/rappid-3.2.0.tgz"
...
}
```

My component looks like below.

```
...
import * as joint from '@clientio/rappid/build/package';
...

function MyComponent(props) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Same error here and I've spent a few hours customizing Jest configuration (with CRA) without success. Have you found a way?

Comment: Are you using rappid library? In my case I had this issue in trail version. It was resolved with licensed version

Answer (score 0):

A bit late with the answer, but maybe someone will find it useful.

The suggested solution by Jest in output above is the correct one. You should add `transformIgnorePatterns` to your Jest config.

If the app uses 'create-react-app', it can be added as an option in an npm script in package.json. I think some Jest config options are not available in 'create-react-app'. If you don't use 'create-react-app', you can just add it to the Jest config.

`"test": "react-scripts test --transformIgnorePatterns \"node_modules/(?!​<package_name>)/\""`

A similar [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52035066/how-to-write-jest-transformignorepatterns) issue can be found here for reference.